# White-space and newline between inline-block elements taking up space

Tags: html, css

I wrote a page with flex columns using 'display:inline-block' as in [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/S7CFk/), but met a problem with white-spaces and newlines:

Even though `.left` and `.right` are both `width:50%`, but since there are white-spaces and a newline between them, they actually take up more than 100% width and so `.right` just goes to next line.

```
<!--demo 1-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="left box">
    </div>
    <div class="right box">
    </div>
</div>
```

Deleting white-spaces and newlines between `.left` and `.right` works, and now they are on the same line, but the HTML is less expressive.

```
<!--demo 2-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="left box">
    </div><div class="right box">
    </div>
</div>
```

So, anyway to keep indents?

Comment: You can float the divs instead of inline-blocking them, though you'll have to worry about clearing the floats after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7CFk/1/)

Add two classes in CSS:

```
.lfloat {
    float: left;
}

.clrflt {
    clear: both;
}
```

Change your HTML code to:

```
<!--demo 1-->
<div class="container">
    <div class="left box lfloat"></div>
    <div class="right box lfloat"></div>
    <div class="clrflt"></div>
</div>
```

### EDITED

inline-blocking adds a 4px border (due to which it shifts the `div` to the next line). Hence, `float` is a more preferred way.

[You can see this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/S7CFk/2/) that uses `display:inline-block`:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        *{padding:0;margin:0}
        ul#container{width:204px}  //Had to add 4px for extra width
         ul#container li{display:inline-block;height:100px;width:100px;background:#666}
        .left{width:50%}
        .right{width:50%;background:#0ca}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul id="container">
           <li>Left</li>
           <li>Right</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[You can read more about these issues at a blog here.](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)

Comment: I know floating works, but isn't `inline-box` more modern and  flexible? G+ uses `inline-box` for columns too.